# Trying to get the width of an h1 tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type = "text/javascript">

var textHeadingArray = ["Bloom Defender", "Civilization Wars", "Flight", "Rebuild 2",  "Wonderputt"];

var textHeadingIndex = 0;

function changeMainImage() {

textHeadingIndex++;
        if (textHeadingIndex >= textHeadingArray.length) {
        textHeadingIndex = 0;   
}

var changeTheHeading = document.getElementById("slidehsowheading").innerHTML = textHeadingArray[textHeadingIndex];

var heading = document.getElementById("slidehsowheading").style.width;

var sizeOfHeading = heading;
alert(sizeOfHeading);

var subtraction = 75 - sizeOfHeading;

var changeTheHeadingAgain = document.getElementById("slidehsowheading").style.left = subtractionRounded + "px";
}

var mainTiming = setInterval("changeMainImage()", 5000);

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1 id = "slidehsowheading">Bloom Defender</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Im trying to use this code to change the heading for a slideshow, I am kinda new to javascript so my problem is that when the alert pops up it returns as null(the alert was just for debugging), so when i try to use the null width from the h1 in this equation it is wrong. The equation is supposed to get the width of the heading after it has been changed by the timer and divid by 2 and subtract that from the width of its background divided by 2 which is 75, with this formula you can center the heading in its background element

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `[object].style.width` only works when the width has been explicitly set in CSS or though the `style.width` method.

Try using the `offsetWidth` property instead:

```
var heading = document.getElementById("slidehsowheading").offsetWidth;
```

Comment: i did exactly what you said but now it displays as 1282

Comment: That means that your element is at its default width (100%). Try this before getting the offsetWidth:
   `document.getElementById("slidehsowheading").style.display="inline-block";`
Then, after that, you can revert it back to block style with:
        `document.getElementById("slidehsowheading").style.display="block";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it after the DOM has loaded. Put your javascript at the end of your body instead of in the head. Also, you should be using console.log instead of alerts for debugging.